# Iterative DNS lookup

Tags: python, dns, network-protocols

I'm trying to implement a simple version of dig as a project with python. I want to implement the DNS lookup by iteration. I read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) document and I thought I should check if the AA(Authoritative Answer) bit in response and if it's not set to 1 I should send the same request to the IP provided in the given response until this bit is set.
When I tried google.com and checked the response with wireshark it provided the correct IP but the AA bit was still 0 and when i kept sending requests it seemed like getting nowhere.
Is this the correct way to do an iterative lookup? If so how to distinguish between authoritative and non-authoritative answers?
Here's the result when asking 1.1.1.1 server for google.com:

```
Flags: 0x8080 Standard query response, No error
1... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a response
.000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
.... .0.. .... .... = Authoritative: Server is not an authority for domain
.... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
.... ...0 .... .... = Recursion desired: Don't do query recursively
.... .... 1... .... = Recursion available: Server can do recursive queries
.... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
.... .... ..0. .... = Answer authenticated: Answer/authority portion was not authenticated by the server
.... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
.... .... .... 0000 = Reply code: No error (0)
```

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a simple version of dig as a project with python." Just to learn things (about DNS and/or Python) or for other reasons? Because otherwise the Python `dnspython` module is all you need for all DNS needs in Python, in provide both an high level and low level interfaces to do everything (from just resolving a record, to build/parse DNS packets down to the wire level)

Comment: "I thought I should check if the AA(Authoritative Answer) bit in response and if it's not set to 1 I should send the same request to the IP provided in the given response until this bit is set." You seem to have some misconceptions here on how the DNS works. You need to make sure first how recursive and authoritative nameservers work and what happens exactly when you query one or the other. The RFCs may be to terse/difficult as an introduction, this article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System could be a gentler approach.

Comment: Alternatively, and to mix my two previous comments, before trying yourself new code, just use dnspython and look at the traces on the network, so that you understand what is happening. Then, if you want to understand DNS/Python better, you can try reproducing the same results (by comparing network traces, but of course some things would change like DNS IDs or casing of names) yourself by looking at the new network traces.

Comment: +1 for @PatrickMevzek three comments. In addition, understand how to get from the root to gTLD to the domain name servers. There are very simple steps to accomplish this. Understand what the AA bit actually means and who sets that bit.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I am not allowed to use any modules for this however I used dig +trace to see what's going on and it first sent NS record requests to root-servers and gtld-servers, then sent an A record request to authoritative server and showed the response but because 1.1.1.1 isn't the authoritative server the AA bit is not set when 1.1.1.1 responds to me. Am I getting this right?

Comment: "I am not allowed to use any modules" You may want to revisit that because it is just plain not doing the intended effect. Instead of relying on a true and tested module that does what you need you will try to basically rewrite part of its features, forgetting edge cases, and hence potentially having far much more bugs that you could have. As for the rest, by definition root and TLD authoritative nameservers are... "authoritative",  indeed, and public DNS resolvers, be it Cloudflare one or Google one or any other one, are recursive nameservers hence never authoritative on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's the result when asking 1.1.1.1 server for google.com:

DNS queries don't always end with an authoritative answer. In fact, `1.1.1.1` is an iterative resolver, so it's his job to query the relevant servers (`root` ->`.com` -> `google.com`) and return a final answer which won't be authoritative since `1.1.1.1` is the one returning it. It will then cache the response and return it whenever someone asks him the same question.

If you want to create a dig-like tool and look for `www.stackoverflow.com`, you need to do what `1.1.1.1` does - start with a root (e.g. `a.root-servers.net.`), and ask it about `.com`. Then ask a `.com` server (e.g. `a.gtld-servers.net`) about `stackoverflow.com`. Finally, ask the server responsible for `stackoverflow.com` (e.g. `ns-1033.awsdns-01.org`) for the `A`/`AAAA` record for `www.stackoverflow.com`. The answer you get from it should be authoritative:

```
> dig www.stackoverflow.com @ns-1033.awsdns-01.org                                                                                                                          ──(Thu,Apr08)─┘

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> www.stackoverflow.com @ns-1033.awsdns-01.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62794
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackoverflow.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.stackoverflow.com.  3600    IN      CNAME   stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com.      3600    IN      A       151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com.      3600    IN      A       151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com.      3600    IN      A       151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com.      3600    IN      A       151.101.129.69

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.      172800  IN      NS      ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.
stackoverflow.com.      172800  IN      NS      ns-358.awsdns-44.com.
stackoverflow.com.      172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.      172800  IN      NS      ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
```

Note the `aa` flag: `flags: qr aa rd`